# Using On-Premise Active Directory (NOT AZURE AD) as an Identity provider store for Identity Server 4

Tags: asp.net-core, identityserver4

does anyone have any idea as to how to use on-premise active directory as an identity store for Identity Server 4? I have successfully done it using IIS, the issue is that it doesn't prompt the user for credentials, it just authenticates them as the user he is logged in to his computer with. This would be okay if the user only had one account, however, that is not the case. Some users have different types of AD accounts. Thank you

Answer (score 0):

Hi and welcome to StackOverflow.

I'm assuming that you have used the method described in the documentation:
http://docs.identityserver.io/en/latest/topics/windows.html

At the end of that page, you can see, that in your `Startup.cs` you have the option to configure the `IISOptions` in your DI.

```
services.Configure<IISOptions>(iis =>
{
    iis.AuthenticationDisplayName = "Windows";
    iis.AutomaticAuthentication = false;
});
```

This is where you disable the automatic IIS authentication, and you prompt the user for username and password on every login.

Comment: Yea, I did everything the documentation said and it works! but... it doesn't allow me to sign in with other usernames and passwords. I need this functionality because some users will have 2 types of accounts and the method described in the documentation automatically logs you in based on what you used to log in to your compute using IIS.

Comment: Thank you for the response however .